# Get multiple shortcode attribute values

Tags: shortcode, customization

I'm trying to get several values from a shortcode. I tried several things without success.

The shortcode looks like this:

```
[myshortcode metakey="<field_key:key1, title:Title 1><field_key:key2, title:Title 2><field_key:key3, title:Title 3> ]
```

How would I get the field_key values? So in this case key1, key2 and key3?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? And why do you need such a complicated single attribute? Exactly what things did you try? Also, ___post the code that processes the shortcode___.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Well it's a bit to complex to explain. But let's say I want to have a list of all posts from a category that is filled in in the shortcode. And above that a custom title.

Let's say this was my shortcode:

`[myshortcode category="<cat:Dogs, title: My dogs><cat:Cats, title: My Cats>"]`

Then I would somehow know how to get the values out of the shortcode.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to shove everything into a single attribute, or a single shortcode even. The string parsing you have to do will get more and more complicated. Try this:

```
function myshortcode_cb( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
      'cat' => '',
      'title' => ''
    ), 
    $atts
  );
  //   var_dump($atts); // debug
  return "{$atts['cat']} :: {$atts['title']}";
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode','myshortcode_cb');
```

With this:

```
[myshortcode cat="key1" title="Title 1" /]
```

And create a shortcode for each case.

Comment: That's not the answer to this question, tho.